# javascript create json object from data table

Tags: javascript

There are two tables work plan and time breaks. I got problem with preparing the json data.

I want the json data look like below.

> {"monday":{"start":"","end":"","breaks":[{"start":"","end":""},{"start":"","end":"0"}]},"tuesday":{"start":"","end":"","breaks":[{"start":"","end":""}}...

[Table work plan and time breaks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViLqH.png)

```js
 $('#save-logic').click(function() {
      
       var TableDataWork = new Array();
       var TableDataBreak = new Array();
       var timeBreak = new Array();
    var dayOfBreak={};
    var dayOfWork ={};
   
      //get data from work plan table
    $('.working-plan tbody tr').each(function(roww, trw){
      
     dayOfWork = $(trw).find('td:eq(0)').text().replace(/\s/g, "");
        
        //get data from time breaks table
    $('.breaks tbody tr').each(function(rowb, trb){
   
      dayOfBreak = $(trb).find('td:eq(0)').find('select').val();
      timeBreak[rowb]={
       'start' : $(trb).find('td:eq(1)').find('input').val(),
       'end' : $(trb).find('td:eq(2)').find('input').val(),
     };
       TableDataWork[roww]={
            dayOfWork: {
              'start' : $(trw).find('td:eq(1)').find('input').val(),
              'end' : $(trw).find('td:eq(2)').find('input').val(),
              'breaks' :  timeBreak,
            },};
      });
      
    });
     TableDataWork.shift(); 
     alert(TableDataWork.toSource()); 
});
```

Comment: Once you have the data structured as you want it, call JSON.stringify(thing) to convert it to JSON.  For example: `var thing = {x:1, y:2}; var jsonString = JSON.stringify(thing);`

Comment: Let's me try. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I think var JSON.stringify() would be the option. Once you have created the `TableDataWork.toSource()` you could convert it to JSON by simply calling this function.

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(TableDataWork.toSource());
```

Comment: Let's me try. Thank you.